# How to enable Nautilus desktop management in Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I'm using Gnome Shell with the following extensions: weather, dock, window-navigator, user-theme, alternative-status-menu, noa11y. I checked "Have file manager handle the desktop" in Gnome Tweak Tool, at first the desktop icons were shown regularly, but upon reboot they went awol. Is there anything else I need to do or could it be a conflict with any of my extensions? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I assume you've also selected the items you want displayed on the desktop in Gnome Tweak Tool? What happens when you disable your extensions and restart the shell?

Comment: I did, but still no trace of desktop handling.

Comment: I haven't solved it but I found a workaround: I simply added the "nautilus -n" command to my startup applications. This way, after a few glitchy instants, the desktop starts correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is by design.

As per [this blog post](http://jeff.ecchi.ca/blog/2010/07/25/desktop-in-the-shell/) on the design of gnome shell:

> TL;DR/summary: the desktop metaphor sucks. We are stuck with a limited
>   surface, limited file management tools, and a background that actively
>   impairs legibility of the files sitting on it (unless you’re using a
>   solid black background).

As such, it was removed from gnome shell as far as I can tell.