# How do I get Nautilus to handle the desktop succesfully in Gnome Shell?

Tags: nautilus, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable Nautilus desktop management in Gnome Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78327/how-to-enable-nautilus-desktop-management-in-gnome-shell)

In [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78327/how-to-enable-nautilus-desktop-management-in-gnome-shell) question,

I asked how to enable desktop management in Gnome Shell. Even though I managed to enable it, I ever since had this issue: [image: here]

Note that the background is a distortion of my GDM login screen background and that there are no items on the desktop. The desktop backrground and items reappear normally as soon as Nautilus is opened, however executing `nautilus -q` as a startup process doesn't restore it. It is minor, but an annoyance nonetheless. Thanks for your contributions!

Comment: I would first try returning to the default theme as sometimes gnome (gtk and gnome-shell) themes cause problems. If that is not the issue, what video card do you have ?

Comment: I already tested the instance disabling all extensions (I have a bunch running), but to no avail. Video card is ATI Radeon 4500.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is marked for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,